# How can I store height info from GPS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gps, xyz

I want to use QGIS as a tool for collecting GPS-Data in the field. One use case would be simple surevy tasks where I want to store the three dimensional position of points. QGIS is working fine on the Windows 8.1 Tablet-PC and it is getting NMEA Data from an external GPS-Receiver. The position is shown on the map and I can store points (and lines) but they only contain the two dimensional positional info - so the height information is lost.

How can I QGIS make store the height info?

Comment: Are you sure that your GPS-Receiver configured correctly? Points imported from my Garmin hiking GPS have the elevation data in attributes. Though there is no elevation data if you open track as lines (for obvious reasons).

Comment: @SS_Rebelious I think in this case, the OP is trying to capture points directly in QGIS using the GPS panel, instead of importing GPS data after it's been collected with the GPS Device - at which point it probably would be fully attributed with x,y,z info.

Comment: Yes, SaultDon is right.In fact the coordinates are calculated on the PC by RTKNavi. I can see three dimensional position data in RTKNavi and they are sent to a gpsd port on localhost in NMEA format. So the height info is there, but it is not stored by QGIS.